# Conditional Emails from google forms spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-statements, google-forms

I am trying to send conditional emails to people who submit a google form based on their responses.
Essentially, I need a code that reads one column and then sends an email message to the email address they supply. I need it to do this every time the form is submitted.

Here is what the sheet looks like: [four column google sheet with timestamp, name, email address, and state fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIrBj.png)

This is my first script so I've figured out how to send an email by pointing to a specific cell, but am having trouble figuring out how to have it trigger each time the form is submitted and how to point it to a full column rather than a specific cell.

Here is some code I've written that does not work. I'm really new to this so I'm sure there are plenty of beginner mistakes. :

```js
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
  .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
  .onFormSubmit()
  .create();

if (lastRow.getvalues() == "NY") {
    function SendEmail() {
  // Fetch the email address
var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1").getRange("C2");
var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue();
// Send Alert Email.
var message = 'This is your NY Alert email!'; // Second column
var subject = 'Your NY Google Spreadsheet Alert';
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
} }

else (lastRow.getvalues() == "MA")  {
  function SendEmail() {
  // Fetch the email address
var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1").getRange("C2");
var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue();
// Send Alert Email.
var message = 'This is your MA Alert email!'; // Second column
var subject = 'Your MA Google Spreadsheet Alert';
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
```

Thank you for any help, insight, or resources!

Comment: lastRow is undefined

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this:

```
function createTrigger() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
    .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();
}
function myFunction(e) {
  const list = ["NY", "MA"];
  if (~list.indexOf(e.values[3]) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(e.values[2], 'Your NY Google Spreadsheet Alert', 'This is your NY Alert email!');
  }
}
```

- [Spreadsheet onFormSubmit Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)